# How do you change the value to an acceptable value after a NumberBox's ValueChanged event is triggered using WinUI3?

Tags: c#, state, controls, eventhandler, winui-3

I have a list of Images with corresponding NumberBoxes in a GridView. This is the XAML:

```xml
<DataTemplate
    x:Key="CardListView_ItemTemplate"
    x:DataType="local:CardItem">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image
            x:Name="EditorImage"
            MaxWidth="236"
            DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
            FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout="{StaticResource ImagePreviewFlyout}"
            Tapped="Image_Tapped" />
        <NumberBox
            x:Name="EditorNumberBox"
            Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            SmallChange="1"
            SpinButtonPlacementMode="Inline"
            Value="0" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I use code to display the correct pictures, but I am having trouble with the timing of the handlers. The goal is to have handlers on the NumberBoxes, so when the value changes on one NumberBox I can update the data, and change the value of the NumberBox back to it's last value if it is an invalid value. Each picture has a corresponding NumberBox that needs to be in the correct state. When I try to change the NumberBox text in a callback, after the callback is finished, the control changes its value back to what it was going to change it to, so the UI is in an invalid state!

I manage the handlers like this

```cs
private Dictionary<string, TypedEventHandler<NumberBox, NumberBoxValueChangedEventArgs>> handlers = new();
...
private void UpdateListView(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.InRecycleQueue)
    {
        var templateRoot = args.ItemContainer.ContentTemplateRoot as Grid;
        var box = templateRoot.FindName("EditorNumberBox") as NumberBox;
        var item = args.Item as CardItem;
        if (handlers.ContainsKey(item.id))
        {
            box.ValueChanged -= handlers[item.id];
        }
        handlers.Remove(item.id);
    }

    if (args.Phase == 0)
    {
        args.RegisterUpdateCallback(ShowImage);
        args.Handled = true;
    }
}

private void ShowImage(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Phase == 1)
    {
        var templateRoot = args.ItemContainer.ContentTemplateRoot as Grid;
        var item = args.Item as CardItem;
        var box = templateRoot.FindName("EditorNumberBox") as NumberBox;
        if (item.Limit == -1)
        {
            box.Maximum = 60;
        }
        else
        {
            box.Maximum = item.Limit;
        }
        box.Minimum = 0;
        TypedEventHandler<NumberBox, NumberBoxValueChangedEventArgs> handler =
            (box, args) =>
            {
                int diff = (int)args.NewValue - (int)args.OldValue;
                int newCount = m_viewModel.getTotalCount() + diff;
                // Strangely, this is true when args.NewValue has value NaN in the debugger
                if (args.NewValue != double.NaN)
                {
                    if (newCount > 0 && newCount <= 60)
                    {
                        Debug.Assert(m_viewModel.ChangeCount(args, item));
                    }
                }
                // This is the Text that gets overwritten after the handler is finished
                box.Text = item.GetCount().ToString();
            };
        handlers[item.id] = handler;
        box.Text = item.GetCount().ToString();
        box.ValueChanged += handler;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the handler's text update is overwritten after the callback finishes.

What needs to be done to fix these issues?

Comment: Can you use a NumberFormatter?

Comment: Hmmm, adding binding and changing the Value instead of the Text seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `box.Text` to `box.Value` as well as binding `item.Count` to the NumberBox.Value property, has made it so there are no invalid states, though the behavior of the NumberBox is inconsistent. Some times it will reset a number that is too high to the min, and other times to the max.